# Bound for sum of squares $r_{2k}(m)$ for $m \geq 1$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I happened to read in (Iwaniec-Kowalkski) Analytic Number Theory book that the Sum of Squares function satisfies the bound $r_{2k}(m) << m^{k-1+\epsilon}$ for $m \geq 1$. But $\epsilon$ is not mentioned explicitly as positive here (though I believe so). Can someone clarify about that? Also, would there be any obvious (or even non-obvious) reason why such an implied constant can't exist for negative $\epsilon$, i.e., if it is so?

Comment: Let $A(n) = \{ x\in \Bbb{R}^k, \exists m \in \Bbb{Z^k},\|m\|^2 = n, \|x-m\| < 1/2\}$ and $B(r) = \{ x \in \Bbb{R^k}, \|x\| < r\}$ then $r_k(n) \le \frac{Vol(A(n))}{Vol(B(1/2))} \le \frac{Vol(B(n^{1/2}+1/2) - B(n^{1/2}-1/2))}{B(1/2)}= \frac{(n^{1/2}+1/2)^k-(n^{1/2}-1/2)^k}{(1/2)^{k}}$. The lower bound is obtained by summing over $n\le N$.

Comment: I tried to analyse/understand what you told for $k=2$ and ended up noticing that you are bounding $r_k(n)$ by the difference in the area between the concentric circles given. For $k=2$, I got $r_2(n) \leq 8\sqrt(n)$. But how does this help me? Can you please give behaviour or some information about Big O of RHS term(in your expression)? Particularly, how is this giving information about my question of $\epsilon$ being negative or positive? I am new to analyic number theory techniques.

Comment: @reuns have you noticed my comment?

Comment: For the case $k=2$ search about the [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem)